# iOS Swift - Debugging Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I'm working on an app and it has horrible memory leaks.
What I observed so far is the more I use the app, the more memory it consumes. I initially thought it could be the way its navigation was handled. We have a slide menu framework written in Objective C. In its Swift file (header is handled) I added the following code:

```
if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
       if let viewControllers = window.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
                for viewController in viewControllers {
            print("" + viewController.debugDescription)
    }
}}
```

The print function indicates that all viewControllers get in fact dismissed however the memory usage doesn't go down appropriately.
Now I started using the "Debug Memory Graph".
That's one example to what I got:
[image]
As you can see, I can't find any hints to what those memory leaks are related to. I can't tell anything from the graph.

Using the app more and more gave me memory leaks related to the following:
CoreFoundation, libswiftCore.dylib and Foundation.

I'm just so lost and I don't know how to proceed with debugging these leaks as there is no additional information to help me pinpoint the cause/swift file causing the leaks.

PS: I'm not the sole developer on this project. I'm pretty much carrying out the work after the previous developer and I've seen bad coding practices all over the place. Rewriting isn't a feasible option.

Comment: Try simulating memory warning to the app to see if it will decrease the memory. Released objects are not necessarily released from memory immediately.

Comment: A good test for leaky view controllers: http://holko.pl/2017/06/26/checking-uiviewcontroller-deallocation/. Also if checking for subviews, use Allocations instrument and Leaks instrument.

Comment: @YunusErenGüzel Can you clarify? How and where I should do the memory simulation? And I don't know when exactly the app would send memory warnings. I'm afraid it may send memory warnings after a huge memory consumption which is undesired at the first place. I want to capture the leaks as early as possible.

Comment: Go to simulator, from menu, Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning. You can check if it really decrease or not. While memory leaks are problem, the problem may not be as dramatic as you thought.

Comment: @YunusErenGüzel Simulate Memory Warning slightly helped but going back to the starting point of the app (home screen) after using the app for a bit, I still notice there is an extra memory usage (10s of megabytes, ~100 mb in total) which will keep increasing the more I use the app.
Also, what does Simulate Memory Warning does exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used Instruments to debug memory leaks. I read the apple docs to figure out how to use Instruments and it was pretty helpful -- specifically the first section: **To look for memory leaks**. I found leaks that I wasn't able figure out using debug memory graph.

[Instruments User Guide: Finding Memory Leaks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html)